# Python threading not working as it is supposed to work

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm following Bucky's Python [tutorial](https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=98&video=20190) and in his video of threading, he got this output (not exactly):

```
Send out messages
Send out messages
Send out messages
Receive messages
Send out messages
Receive messages
Send out messages
Receive messages
Send out messages
Receive messages
Send out messages
Receive messages
Receive messages
Receive messages
```

but when I tried writing similar code, I got this output:

```
Receiving messages...
Receiving messages...
Receiving messages...
Receiving messages...
Receiving messages...
Receiving messages...
Receiving messages...
Receiving messages...
Receiving messages...
Receiving messages...
Sending messages...
Sending messages...
Sending messages...
Sending messages...
Sending messages...
Sending messages...
Sending messages...
Sending messages...
Sending messages...
Sending messages...
```

Here's my code:

```
# threading

import threading

class Messenger(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for _ in range(10): # '_' is used when you want to run a for loop but don't care about the varialble
            print(threading.currentThread().getName())

x = Messenger(name='Sending messages...')
y = Messenger(name='Receiving messages...')

x.start()
y.start()
```

So, is there something wrong with my code or what is wrong here and why my output is different from Bucky's output?

Comment: i think this is because of gil(global interpretor lock) property of python,ie it will execute only one thread at a time https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock

Comment: Running it different times, I get both kinds of output. It depends mainly on when the OS allocates time to your threads. You can add a little `sleep` to see it happening more slowly - and you will notice that the order in which each of your threads executes isn't guaranteed. That's the whole point of using them: they run independently. If the order of execution is important to you, don't use threads, or use some kind of synchronization.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I've tested the code 9-10 times and every time I'm getting the same output. I know what's the point of using threading and that's why I'm using it. What do you think about the `gil` point given by akhilviswam above? How to disable it?

Comment: @akhilviswam is there any way of disabling the `gil`?

Comment: no its default,you can use multiprocessing instead with pool@HammadNasir

Comment: @akhilviswam actually I'm just getting started with Python so I pretty much don't understand what you said.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html@HammadNasir

Answer (score 0):

Order of output is not guaranteed when you use threads. The order in which threads are executed depends on your OS. I got a totally different output on my system.